# Compare two unequal matrix some specific column without using for loop

Tags: matlab

I want to compare two matrices without using a for loop. Given

```
A=[2 1 8;
   2 4 7;
   2 3 7;
   3 5 2;
   5 1 4;
   5 6 2;
   5 3 7];

B=[3 6 5;
   1 4 2];
```

Now I want to compare `col(2)` two of matrix `B` with `col(2)` two of matrix `A` and at the same time  `col(3)` three of matrix `B` and `col(1)` one of matrix `A`. Now I want to get the result from matrix `A` like this:

```
c=[2 4 7;
   5 6 2];
```

Comment: I am very unclear as to what you are asking.  First - do you mean "column"?  `A` and `B` have different numbers of rows so their columns are not directly comparable.  Second - can you explain how matrix `c` was calculated?  I don't see how that is the result of a comparison between A and B.

Comment: It was a mistake. It should be unequal rows. Matrix C is calculated from matrix A by comparing col(2) of matrix B with col(2) of matrix A and at the same time col(3) of matrix B and col(1) of matrix A.

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't make sense.  Column 2 of matrix B is this: `[ 2 4 ]` and column 2 of matrix A is this: `[ 1 4 3 5 1 6 3 ]`.  They cannot be compared as they are different lengths.

Comment: @mizanbuet do you mean with "comparing col(2) of matrix B with col(2) of matrix A" >> "compare column 2 of B with column 2 of A" ??

Answer (score 0):

I think @mizanbuet wants to extract rows from `A` where the 3rd element of the row is in the  first column of `B` and the 2nd element in the row is in the 2nd column of `B`.

Easy with some [ismember](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) and [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html):

```
A2inB2 = ismember(A(:,2),B(:,2));
A1inB3 = ismember(A(:,1),B(:,3));
c = A( A2inB2 & A1inB3, :);
```